# Python Import custom library from another directory

Tags: python

I have the following folder format

```
Main Folder
    -DataManagement
        -Libraries
             -TransformLibrary
                  __init__.py
                  transform.py
        -DataUsage
             -TransformData
                  main.py
```

I wish to call Transform.py from main.py. However I need this to be relative, meaning that if somebody clones my project, it can run without changing any paths.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use `sys.path` to both find your current directory, and include your module in `sys.path` so that Python can find it. However, this solution is a bit messy:

```
import sys
import os

# Get current directory
current_dir = sys.path[0]

# Create path to 'Main Folder/DataManagement/Libraries'
search_dir = os.path.join(current_dir.split('DataUsage')[0], 'Libraries')

# Make Python search for new path
sys.path.append(search_dir)

from TransformLibrary import transform # transform.py is imported
```